# Take Screen shot with Notification Drawer iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Is there any way to take screen shot along with the `Notification`
    Drawer?

Actually I'm working on a **POC** where I'm to take a screenshot, when `iMessage` comes and `Message notification Drawer` pops up, So can that `Message notification Drawer` be capture along with the `view`? 
and if it's possible, Apple will allow to such application submission to the App Store.

Comment: were you able to receive notification when sms received ?

Comment: @Basheer_CAD it can come in three different ways according to the setup has been made by user,  top of the screen, as an alert and no alert.